# Convert HTML to Excel document using iText C#

Tags: c#, excel, itext

Is there is a way to convert HTML file to Excel using iText 7?
If the iText doesn't support, what is the the best way to convert HTML file to Excel?
Thanks

sample HTML code as below:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Can you add to this question a sample of the HTML you are trying to convert?

Comment: I added sample HTML.

Comment: In the Java world you would use Apache POI, but I don't know the C# equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know iText makes PDF files. You won't be able to produce Excel files with this. (The two kinds of files have very little in common.)

The best way to convert HTML to Excel can depend on a number of factors: you tagged this question with C#. Are you running on a server or are you trying to automate an instance of Excel? What framework are you using? Do you have access to a filesystem? .Net Core?

You can look at the Microsoft OpenXML library for one option to create Excel files, but in my experience it can be brittle and require a lot of troubleshooting to get started. But it doesn't need Excel installed or licensed.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. I'm using ASP.NET MVC framework. I have experience with OpenXML. I just want to  keep HTML file as template and using this template HTML file, generate Excel sheet. I'll try out OpenXML.