# Is it possible to create Excel file using iText

Tags: c#, excel, itext7

I have HTML file as below.
I use this HTML to create PDF using iText. I'm planning to use same HTML and generate Excel file.
Is there possible way to make Excel files with itext7?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Some text </p>
<p>paragraph </p>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise what is the best way to generate Excel file by using the HTML file?
I'm using .NET MVC.

Comment: no, there is not. iText's is a pdf tool, not an excel one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to Excel document using iText C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602414/convert-html-to-excel-document-using-itext-c-sharp)

Comment: Does you question really touches only the ability of iText or you do want to create Excel exports on .NET MVC?

Comment: I want to verify the ability of iText and it is not possible, best way to convert HTMl to Excel file in .NET MVC

Comment: look's like a copy from other site https://www.anycodings.com/1questions/5189219/is-it-possible-to-create-excel-file-using-itext

Answer (score 3):

You can't generate Excel with iText because it's only for PDF. Instead use Apache POI.

Comment: Thanks Mikev. Apache POI can use with Java. But I'm using .NET MVC.